# Resetting passwords in AD LDS not honoring password history via Java ldap api

Tags: java, passwords, ldap, reset

I am trying to implement reset password functionality for accounts in Windows 2012 R2 AD LDS via java ldap api. But it is not honoring password history constraint. When I tried to implement change password it is enforcing password history. I am using the following code to reset password.

```
@Override
public void updatePassword(String password) throws LdapException {
    try {
        String quotedPassword = "\"" + password + "\""; 
        char unicodePwd[] = quotedPassword.toCharArray(); 
        byte pwdArray[] = new byte[unicodePwd.length * 2]; 
        for (int i=0; i<unicodePwd.length; i++) { 
            pwdArray[i*2 + 1] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] >>> 8); 
            pwdArray[i*2 + 0] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] & 0xff); 
        } 
        ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[]{new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE,new BasicAttribute("UnicodePwd", pwdArray))};
        LdapContext ldapContext = (LdapContext)ldapTemplate.getContextSource().getReadWriteContext();

        final byte[] controlData = {48,(byte)132,0,0,0,3,2,1,1};
        BasicControl[] controls = new BasicControl[1];
        final String LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_OID = "1.2.840.113556.1.4.2239";
        controls[0] = new BasicControl(LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_OID, true, controlData);
        ldapContext.setRequestControls(controls);

        ldapContext.modifyAttributes(getRelativeDistinguishedName(), mods);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new LdapException("Failed to update password for:" + this.getDistinguishedName(), e);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Are you using an admin account for the reset? That might skip the history (and other) constraint.

Comment: Where does it say that replacing the password should honour the password history? And why should an admin reset do so? The idea is that the admin sets it to 99999999 or something, tells the user, the `pwdReset` attribute is set to true, the user logs in with 99999999 or whatever and is then immediately forced to change the password. No reason for the password history to be involved here.