# Updating an AD user's password respecting password history policy

Tags: c#, active-directory

Trying to update an AD user's password while respecting the password history policy. Most of the code is taken from Michael Frommhold's article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/fieldcoding/resetting-passwords-honoring-password-history-or-whats-happening-under-the-hood-when-changing-resetting-passwords). I've found a couple similar posts on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353869/ldap-server-policy-hints-oid-control-not-working-in-ad-lds-windows-server-2012r2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676933/resetting-passwords-in-ad-lds-not-honoring-password-history-via-java-ldap-api)) but neither of those solutions worked in my case. No matter what combination of settings I use the password is still updated, whether it's been used in the past or not.

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

- Tried using both the old deprecated OID 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2066 and the new OID 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2239
- Tried setting the value for the DirectoryControl to Berconverted 0x1 and the byte array byte[] { 48, (byte)132, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1 } found in a different post
- Confirmed with ldap.exe that the RootDSE supports both 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2066 = ( POLICY_HINTS_DEPRECATED ) and 1.2.840.113556.1.4.2239 = ( POLICY_HINTS )
- Tried manually changing the password for the account to verify that the password I'm setting is definitely in the account's history

Here's the code I'm currently running

```
public bool ResetUserPassword(string userID, string password)
{
    bool isSuccess = false;

    using (LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(ADServer + ":636"))
    {
        NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(ADAdminUserID, ADAdminPwd, ADDomain);
        ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
        ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;

        // Enforce LDAP version 3
        ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;

        ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback((con, cer) => true);

        // Bind connection
        ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);

        // the 'unicodePWD' attribute is used to handle pwd handling requests
        string attribute = "unicodePwd";

        // our modification control
        DirectoryAttributeModification[] damList = null;

        // the modifiy request
        ModifyRequest mrCall = null;

        // modification control for the replace operation
        DirectoryAttributeModification damReplace = new DirectoryAttributeModification();

        // attribute to handle
        damReplace.Name = attribute;

        // value to be send with the request
        damReplace.Add(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(string.Format("\"{0}\"", password)));

        // this is a replace operation
        damReplace.Operation = DirectoryAttributeOperation.Replace;

        // combine modification controls
        damList = new DirectoryAttributeModification[] { damReplace };

        // create DN string
        string distinguishedName = "CN=TestUser,OU=Test,DC=com";

        // init modify request
        mrCall = new ModifyRequest(distinguishedName, damList);

        // the actual extended control OID                     
        string LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_OID = "1.2.840.113556.1.4.2239";

        // build value utilizing berconverter
        //byte[] value = BerConverter.Encode("{i}", new object[] { 0x1 });
        byte[] value = new byte[] { 48, (byte)132, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1 };

        // init extended control
        DirectoryControl pwdHistory = new DirectoryControl(LDAP_SERVER_POLICY_HINTS_OID, value, true, true);

        // add extended control to modify request
        mrCall.Controls.Add(pwdHistory);

        DirectoryResponse drResult = null;

        string msg = "";

        try
        {
            /* send the request into the DirectoryConnection
             * and receive the response */
            drResult = ldapConnection.SendRequest(mrCall);

            // display result code
            msg = TranslateEx(drResult, null, distinguishedName);
        }
        catch (DirectoryOperationException doex)
                { msg = TranslateEx(drResult, doex, distinguishedName); }
        catch (Exception ex)
                { msg = TranslateEx(drResult, ex, distinguishedName); }

        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    return isSuccess;
}
```

Response from the server looks like this:
| Name | Value | Type |
| ---- | ----- | ---- |
| dr | {System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ModifyResponse} | System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryResponse {System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ModifyResponse} |
| Controls | {System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryControl[0]} | System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryControl[] |
| ErrorMessage | null | string |
| MatchedDN | "" | string |
| Referral | {System.Uri[0]} | System.Uri[] |
| RequestId | null | string |
| ResultCode | Success | System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ResultCode |
| directoryControls | null | System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryControl[] |
| directoryMessage | null | string |
| directoryReferral | null | System.Uri[] |
| directoryRequestID | null | string |
| dn | "" | string |
| dsmlNS | null | System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager |
| dsmlNode | null | System.Xml.XmlNode |
| dsmlRequest | false | bool |
| requestID | null | string |
| result | Success | System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ResultCode |

Looking for any guidance or ideas that I haven't tried. I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: This is by design. A password _change_ is a separate type of operation from a password _reset_. History enforcement only applies to the former.

Comment: We spent couple of attemps to solve this and nothing really works. We had to build an auxiliary storage for bcrypted password history and just refer to this storage to validate the new password against the history. Not the solution you ask for, rather, a confirmation that the expected way to solve this might not work at all and only workarounds should be considered.

Comment: Yes, the MSFT article I linked mentions this. But it also provides a method for respecting password history when doing a password reset.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - I was afraid of that. Thanks for the response!